# Making Multiple Back-to-Back CSS Transitions Smooth & Seamless Instead of Jerky or Choppy

Tags: javascript, css, transform, css-transitions

When transitioned CSS properties are changed back to back, especially when the next property change starts before any previous transition has finished, the result is a herky-jerky look and feel of the overall effect (because the next transition stops the previous, and starts out slowly). Removing the transition (or setting it to 0s temporarily) during the period of rapid property changes may or may not be smooth enough either. What I really want is a decent way to tween from one transition to another seamlessly, especially in cases where one transition hasn't quite finished before another begins.

### Use Case: when properties are rapidly changed via JavaScript

Say an element is being dragged via mouse or touch. Browsers fire those mouse/touch events when it's convenient for them, and browsers don't always fire such events in a timely fashion. Usually they are indeed fired smoothly, but sometimes there can be a significant delay between two events firing. The resulting effect can either be jerky or choppy, depending on whether or not you have a transition set on the element (see Dilemma). Ideally, transitions ***should*** be capable of smoothing out the overall effect, **if only there was a CSS property that tells the browser to continue subsequent transitions with the same rate of speed as any currently animating transitions rather than stop the current one before starting the next**. I haven't come across such a property yet, though.

### Specific Example

Take for instance an element moving across the screen (to keep it simple). Say there's a button that triggers the element to move between a designated start and end position on the screen, the 'animation' for which is handled via `transition: 1s` then adding a class that changes the location of the element via a transform property. Voila, the element is 'animated' from its start to its end position. Now say you want the user to also have the ability to drag or swipe the element from between its start and end positions. Naturally, this would be handled via some JavaScript (for now, perhaps until HTML6—as the HTML5 `draggable` attribute doesn't work for the majority of touchscreens/mobile devices yet anyway).

So, you'd set up your event listeners for the mouse/touch events, and handle the transformation of the movable element via `mousedown`/`mousemove` or `touchstart`/`touchmove`, setting a relevant transform value with each movement. Then when they let up on the mouse or touch (`mouseup` or `touchend`) you'd finish moving the element to its end position (or move it back to its start position, if desired) by removing the dynamic styles applied by the `mousemove` or `touchmove` events, and perhaps adding a class that would move the element to its end position if certain conditions are met.

### The dilemma

If you DON'T dynamically set the transition to 0s while the element is being dragged, then each time a transitioned property is changed, if a previous transition is still going, it stops dead in its tracks and a new transition starts from the stopped point, resulting in a herky-jerky effect.

If you DO dynamically set the transition to 0s while the element is being dragged, then when there's a significant delay between two event firings, and the result is a significant change in position, the element just jumps to the new position immediately, rather than smoothly transitioning to the new position, resulting in a choppy.

### Solution Attempts

I've thought of several potential workarounds, but they aren't exactly ideal.

The first is to watch for significant delays between events (or their reported coordinates) and react accordingly by changing the dynamically-set transition property from 0s to something that will animate the transition, but that would likely get cancelled almost immediately by the next event firing which would either change the dynamic transition property back to 0s or else change the position of the element with the dynamic transition still set from the previous transition, causing that transition to stop and the next to start from current position. It also adds extra overhead to the JavaScript code, which I'm not a fan of if there's a better way.

Another is to use `transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1)` for the subsequent transitions, which causes subsequent transitions to start out much faster, but they also end much faster, which isn't necessarily desirable. Also, this approach still has a slightly odd feel to it due to noticeable stuttering when transitioned properties are changed extremely quickly. At least that was my experience in Chrome. It looked smoother when the rate of changes to transitioned properties were not quite so rapid-fire (e.g. slower dragging of the element across the screen).

There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470591/smooth-out-rapid-javascript-driven-position-changes-with-css-transitions), for which the only solution posted also fails to make the overall effect smooth. That solution has the same exact stuttering flaw I mentioned above for rapid-fire changes to properties transitioned with a higher duration of 1s.

It would be a whole lot simpler if there were a CSS property for transitions that tell the browser to continue into a subsequent transition at the same pace without stopping the one nor starting the other from a stand-still. I haven't found such a property yet, however.

If no such property exists yet, is there a better approach to smoothing out such rapid-fire changes to transitioned properties?

Here's some very simple [demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/794sx/), which is unfortunately too simple to exhibit the laggy event firing I speak of, but at least it's a starting point. If I get no decent responses, I'll try to make a more advanced example that utilizes more computational power, to make the event firing lag more evident.

Comment: You made an elaborate explanation of the problem it would have been nice if you wanted solution to a specific problem which's solutions would help in getting answer for your question

Comment: Can we post an answer that go with jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is fine, if it does the trick. I understand some JavaScript may be required if there's no simple solution with pure CSS, though pure CSS is always preferred when possible (minus the event handling). 

I built a [very simple demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/794sx/) using the aforementioned use case, but since it's a very simple example, it's very fast and doesn't suffer from the lagging of the mousemove/touchmove events firing (when `transition: 0s` is set) perceived on more advanced/highly interactive sites. May need to make it a whole lot busier to get the lag to show up.

Comment: Two things: 1) I read your "question" two times and didn't get it: what do you _exactly_ want to animate? Dragging? Sounds like drag and drop of "file items" or such. Why would it be necessary to animate it between say 20px distance? Sounds a bit like overkill. _(Please don't get this as criticism)_ 2) Your fiddle looks nice, wahts wrong with that? Ah I should continue reading... "`that utilizes more computational power`" you say. So you need to utilize more CPU power in an exemplary Fiddle. Is it possible that your code is inefficient and fixing transitions is just a cure for the symptoms?

Comment: Can you cut down the long explanation and just add a "[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: The actual use case experiencing the issues is a full-screen image gallery, with the ability to drag/swipe between photos. The shear size of the photos seems to be what may be causing the lag in performance, which leads to the choppy event firing spree, rather than smooth and seamless. You're probably wondering why I didn't say that to begin with. Well, it's not something that would translate well to a JSFiddle IMHO.

Comment: There are other examples though, such as an element moving across the page, but whose position is controlled/changed via hover of prior siblings using the sibling selector. In such a case, the position isn't constantly changing, but the position change might get triggered before the element has completed it's move/transition, in which case the browser will halt the current transition in progress, before starting the next one. I simply want the ability for the animation to continue at the same rate of speed into the next transition, without being jerked to a halt first.

Comment: What are you using for drag and drop? A jQuery-UI plugin, built if from scratch using lowlevel events (`mousemove`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`)? My experience with jQuery UI D'n'D: if handled the wrong way: they are laggy, jerky. In some special cases its not flexible enough. I had to rewite a whole bunch of it's internal code to get it working for a photo gallery where D'n'D was necessary. Handling the wrong way means e.g. applying it on an detached element and then adding images (which is sometimes not avoidable).

Comment: Without knowing your code it's hard to give some hints. I can recommend building/moving the drag and drop in(to) a "playground" application. There you can isolate the problem and/or re-implement the D'n'D without perhaps errorneous and distracting code around. As said eralier, try to avoid using transitions, it seems in this case they're only cure for unsolved problems. If necessary we can discuss the "playground" here. After building more than 3 applications using D'n'D I can tell you: the 4th will be implemented with pure JS events handling. :) Insisting on Fiddles is a bad habit here. :/

Comment: The code I'm using is almost identical to the simple demo I posted. Apparently I over-MCV'd it.

Answer (score 3):

CSS transitions are a pain when called from JavaScript, especially if they need to start immediately. They work great if you don't have to set new values to the transition CSS property before starting an animation, but when you do you end up with sync and timing issues. Personally, I've had to set the transition values first and then set the actual CSS being transitioned to inside a setTimeout() callback to make sure the transition values take hold first, and that adds slight delays and skips to it.

Browser vendors are working on a better way: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36. But at the moment only Chrome supports it.

In the meantime, if you need to start a new animation in response to a very dynamic user input, I'd suggest going with `requestAnimationFrame`. It performs far better than older JavaScript animation methods (including jQuery) since it's synced to the browser's actual refresh cycle. You can use a transition for the initial animation in your above example, but then kill it and switch to a JavaScript solution using requestAnimationFrame the moment the user interrupts it with their own swiping motion.

(Non-prefixed support for it starts with IE10, FF23, Ch6, and Safari 6.1. For older browsers there's a shim that'll revert to jumpier setTimeouts, but the movement will otherwise work.)

Comment: I agree that browsers or the W3C powers that be need to provide a better way. In the meantime, requestAnimationFrame and/or the [animation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) (or combination of the two) may be a viable if not annoying workaround. With websites become more advanced cases of interactive experiences, I hope it's only a matter of time before this sort of issue is natively resolved without the use of JavaScript. In any case, thanks for taking the time to read and respond!

Comment: By the way, they already are working on a better way for programmatically triggering immediate CSS3-style animations. I updated my answer with a link to it.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that information was worth the whole bounty right there! Definitely glad I awarded it to you. Cheers for the follow-up!

Answer (score 0):

In short: It seems that you expect to be able to rapidly change transformations using javascript, and are not happy with the results of your implementation?

This is a classic case of either:

1. Too bleeding edge.
2. Wrong solution for the wrong task.

Either way, your solution begins elsewhere, and probably involves not using transforms in the way that you are.

It sounds like you might need to have a look at this link:
http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to have to rely on jQuery to handle "throttling" your animations to prevent them from stepping on each other's feet.

Try something like this where jQuery will wait for one animation to complete before firing the next. This is assuming .slideMeLeft and .slideMeDown has animation styling. Once the animation for slideMeLeft has completed, then slideMeDown class is added which will have its own.

```
$('#animatedElement').addClass('slideMeLeft');
$('#animatedElement').one(
        'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
         $('#animatedElement').addClass('slideMeDown');
         );
```